# SVM: Why is Maximize margin == minimize Euclidean norm?

Tags: margin, svm

In the SVM opimization problem, we either want to maximise the margin of `2/||w||`,
or minimise the Euclidean Norm of weight vector w:
`(1/2)*w^t*w`

Can somebody explain to me why the Euclidean Norm is the formula above? And not `1/sqrt(w^t*w)`?
I assume euclidean norm is the Euclidean distance, how do we get to that formula?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the following three are equivalent (under suitable mathematical conditions which are usually met):

- Maximize a quantity `z`.
- Maximize `f(z)`, where `f` is a strictly growing function.
- Minimize `g(z)`, where `g` is a strictly decreasing function.

In your case, set `z=||w||`, and apply the above the other way round. Then minimizing`||w||` is equivalent to minimizing `f(z) = 1/2 ||w||^2`, and to maximizing `g(z) = 2/||w||`.

Comment: ok but how can I convert the two mathematical equations so that they are equivalent?

Comment: I mean 2/||w|| == ||w||/2 if I take the reciprocal...  but ||w|| is not the same as ||w||^2 in the numerator, how do we get there mathematically?

Comment: @user2883596: you not only take the repciprocal, but you also square. So the function I'm talking about is `f(z) = 1/z^2`. Example: say you minimize `2/||w||` and you get the value `1` (i.e. `||w|| = 2`). So no matter how you choose the parameters, `||w||` will never become larger than `2` (if it would, `2/||w||` would not be a minimum). Therefore, `||w||^2` never gets larger than `4`. Now, instead of minimizing `2/||w||`, you could also maximize `||w||^2`. It's equivalent.

Comment: yeah I understand, but I could as well maximize ||w|| instead of ||w||^2, why do we take the squared ||w|| of the one formula, but not the squared ||w|| of the other formula? and divide by 2 instead?

Comment: @user2883596: because `||w||^2` is differentiable and so much easier to maximize/minimize.

Comment: @user2883596: that factor `1/2` doesn't matter. It's only purpose is to cancel the `2` that comes down when you derive the `||w||^2` term.

Answer (score 0):

We have two boundaries ⋅+=1 and ⋅+=−1 and a middle one which is ⋅+=0. Now we want to figure out the distance between each of these two lines with the middle one. If we call the distance .

We consider a point z on ⋅+=1, then setting this point z as the origin, the point on ⋅+=0 would be −⋅||||, here, the distance between the middle line and  ⋅+=1 is the distance between z and −⋅||||

now since this point is on ⋅+=0, we would have:

⋅(−⋅ / ||||)+ = 0

⋅+ −⋅⋅ / |||| = 0

we know that since z is located on ⋅+=1, then ⋅+ equals 1, hence:

1 −⋅⋅ / |||| = 0

⋅⋅ / |||| = 1

⋅ ||||^2 / |||| = 1

⋅ |||| = 1

= 1/||||